# Making reactions with Partial Events

Tags: bots, discord.js

I've made a code for verify command, it's reacting to certain embed. But when I reboot the bot won't recognize it, so users can still react but won't get role at all. I've heard I can use Partial Event but I don't want to make it inside `index.js`.

Code:

```
    let wembed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setAuthor("Test")
    .setColor("PURPLE")
    .setDescription(arg1) 

    const reactmessage = await client.channels.cache.get(chx).send(wembed)
    await reactmessage.react('✅');

    const filter = (reaction, user) => reaction.emoji.name === '✅' && !user.bot;
    const collector = reactmessage.createReactionCollector(filter);

    collector.on('collect', async reaction => {      
        const user = reaction.users.cache.last();
        const guild = reaction.message.guild;
        const member = guild.member(user) || await guild.fetchMember(user);
        member.roles.add("725747028323205170");
    });
```

If there is a way of doing this help would be appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean you don't want to make it inside of index.js? All you add to index.js is options to the client instance: https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/partials.html#enabling-partials

Comment: Some people told me to make it inside index.js, still i have option inside index.js as you said and its still not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/partials.html#enabling-partials

index.js:

```js
const client = new Client({ partials: ['MESSAGE', 'CHANNEL', 'REACTION'] });
```

your messageReactionAdd file:

```js
module.exports = async (reaction, user) => {
   if(reaction.partial) await reaction.fetch();
}
```

Now all reactions are sent to messageReactionAdd, now you just have to validate the reaction and add the role if it corresponds to the right emoji and the right message

Comment: Adding role part is not working properly but I guess ill fix it