# Is there a way to keep the references of chats, messages and collectors on discord.js after it restarts?

Tags: events, discord.js, discord-interactions

I'm creating a bot to discord, using discord.js, it works with tickets, where a user select the category of problem he want in a select menu, after this, a modal is opened and ask the user a title and a description to the problem. After this, a chat is created for the user with a initial message and at the same time, a message is send to a chat that only admins have permissions, with a button to enter the service and another to finish the service. When the service is complete, the bot send a embed to both chats, asking for a rating, so it needs the collector.

The question is, if the bot crashes or the server crashes, when the bot restart, it loses the connections with those messages, so the buttons does'nt work.

Answer (score 0):

I remember using partials for this kind of stuff. I haven't used them in a long time so I don't really know what will happen, your mileage may vary.

However, it might give you a place to start.

Good luck!

- https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/partials.html#enabling-partials
- https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/reactions.html#listening-for-reactions-on-old-messages
- [Making reactions with Partial Events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62658075/making-reactions-with-partial-events) (for reactions, but idea remains the same)

Comment: It receive the partial events, but it return undefined on the content, like, how can i make they work again?

Comment: @Henrik  You will have to fetch the data again. The links provided by [@Fyxren](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15044122/fyxren) explain in detail how to do this.